# Как в коде заменить событие change на input

Tags: javascript

Есть форма:

```
<input id="weight" name="weight">

<input type="checkbox" value="1" id="doc">

<select id="dist" name="dist" class="form-control">
    <option value="in_city">В городе</option>
    <option value="0_49">От города меньше 50 км </option>
    <option value="50_200">От города 50-200 км</option>
    <option value="200_999">От города больше 200 км</option>
</select>

<input id="final_price" name="final_price" readonly>
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.calc-form').change(function(){
        $dist = $('select#dist').val();
        $weight = $('input#weight').val();
        $sum = {
            "document":{
                "0.3":{"in_city":"1600","0_49":"2200","50_200":"3200","200_999":"4200"},
                "0.5":{"in_city":"2000","0_49":"2400","50_200":"3400","200_999":"4400"},
                "1":{"in_city":"2400","0_49":"2700","50_200":"3700","200_999":"4700"},
                "1.5":{"in_city":"2600","0_49":"3000","50_200":"4000","200_999":"5000"},
                "2":{"in_city":"2800","0_49":"3500","50_200":"4500","200_999":"5500"}
            },
            "no_document":{
                "0.5":{"in_city":"2100","0_49":"2400","50_200":"3400","200_999":"4400"},
                "1":{"in_city":"2450","0_49":"2700","50_200":"3700","200_999":"4700"},
                "1.5":{"in_city":"2650","0_49":"3000","50_200":"4000","200_999":"5000"},
                "2":{"in_city":"2850","0_49":"3500","50_200":"4500","200_999":"5500"}
            }
        };

        //Проверка документ ли или нет
        if( $("#doc").prop('checked') ){
            var item = Object.keys($sum.document).map(item => +item).sort().find(key => key >= $weight);
            $('input#final_price').val($sum.document[item][$dist]);
        } else {
            var item = Object.keys($sum.no_document).map(item => +item).sort().find(key => key >= $weight);
            $('input#final_price').val($sum.no_document[item][$dist]);
        }
    })
});
```

Вопрос как сделать так что бы при вводе в поле вес, final_price менялся мгновенно.

Comment: Не вижу у вас   - **вес**?

Answer (score 0):

Ну во первых для таких целей есть такие фреймворки как Vue, React, Angular:
(пример Vue)

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {'amount': 10}
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type="number" v-model="amount"/>
  Final price: {{amount*30}} <!-- тут можно любую формулу-->
</div>
```

Нативное решение - использовать событие input

```js
document.getElementById("inp").addEventListener("input", function(e)
{
  document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = document.getElementById("inp").value;
});
```

```html
<input id="inp" type="number" value="0">
Full price: <span id="price">0</span>
```